# Traceback when trying to read data from web pages

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Aug 26 17:31:06 2017

@author: Pavan Vallapureddy
"""
"""
Write a program to prompt the user for the URL so it can read any web page. 
You can use split('/') to break the URL into its component parts so you can 
extract the host name for the socket connect call.
"""

import socket

url = input("Enter url: ")
port = int(input("Enter port: "))
urlSplit = url.split("/")
host = urlSplit[2]

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((host, port))
cmd = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".encode
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Enter url: http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt
Enter port: 80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exercise1.py", line 17, in 
    cmd = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".encode
TypeError: must be str, not builtin_function_or_method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the method `encode()` for string instance `cmd`:

```
cmd = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
mysock.send(cmd.encode())
```

Comment: @PavanVallapureddy Glad to help! Please consider accepting this answer. Thanks!